# what is being passed to scrapy DownloaderStats middleware?

Tags: python, oop, twisted, scrapy

I'm trying to alter Scrapy's stats middleware.

Here's Scrapy's stats.py in full:

```
from scrapy.exceptions import NotConfigured
from scrapy.utils.request import request_httprepr
from scrapy.utils.response import response_httprepr

class DownloaderStats(object):

    def __init__(self, stats):
        self.stats = stats

    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
        if not crawler.settings.getbool('DOWNLOADER_STATS'):
            raise NotConfigured
        return cls(crawler.stats)

    def process_request(self, request, spider):
        self.stats.inc_value('downloader/request_count', spider=spider)
        self.stats.inc_value('downloader/request_method_count/%s' % request.method, spider=spider)
        reqlen = len(request_httprepr(request))
        self.stats.inc_value('downloader/request_bytes', reqlen, spider=spider)

    def process_response(self, request, response, spider):
        self.stats.inc_value('downloader/response_count', spider=spider)
        self.stats.inc_value('downloader/response_status_count/%s' % response.status, spider=spider)
        reslen = len(response_httprepr(response))
        self.stats.inc_value('downloader/response_bytes', reslen, spider=spider)
        return response

    def process_exception(self, request, exception, spider):
        ex_class = "%s.%s" % (exception.__class__.__module__, exception.__class__.__name__)
        self.stats.inc_value('downloader/exception_count', spider=spider)
        self.stats.inc_value('downloader/exception_type_count/%s' % ex_class, spider=spider)
```

In  the `from_crawler` classmethod, what is it, exactly, that's getting passed in?

Comment: `.from_crawler()` is called (at least) in `scrapy/middleware.py` in `.from_settings`, which is called in `scrapy/core/scraper.py` through `itemproc_cls.from_crawler(crawler)`. `.from_crawler()` returns an instance of a middleware class, initialized with a parameter from a crawler, in case of `DownloaderStats` it's a stats object (`cls(crawler.stats)`). It's another way of calling `DownloaderStats(crawler.stats)` (but the spider doesnt always know how to properly initialize all its middleware classes)

Comment: You're welcome @Charles S. I'll have to re-read your question for the 2nd part

Comment: Just posted an answer trying to help you understand the class method and how the DownloaderStats are instantiated. As for your second question, what do you mean that you're trying to "capture" all Twisted errors, and what do you mean that you'd rather send the request and the ex_class "back up to an item pipeline"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, `DownloaderStats(object)` doesn't mean that DownloaderStats is being passed an object, it means that the DownloaderStats class extends the `object` class.

In your class method, `cls` is the class being called, in this case `DownloaderStats`. So the code `cls(crawler.stats)` could be thought of as `DownloaderStats(crawler.stats)`, which instantiates an object of the class DownloaderStats. Instantiating objects in Python cause their `__init__` method to be called, so the value of `crawler.stats` gets assigned to the `stats` parameter of the `__init__` method, which then gets assigned to `self.stats`.